# Image is mis-aligned on ~30% of page loads

Tags: html, css

About 30% of the time when I load my site my hero image is mis-aligned.

Website here: tomcritchlow.com

Screenshot of the misaligned image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeT9M.png

Thanks!

EDIT: here's the code so you don't have to visit the site:

```
.container{
width:700px;
margin:auto;    
}

.roundimage{
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="roundimage"><img class="homepageimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/j9NkIPK.jpg?1" /></div>
```

Comment: If possible, please update you question to include examples of the HTML and CSS that demonstrate the problem. Just as a guess, I'd say your image is sometimes loaded before the CSS and sometimes after, but without seeing the code, guessing is all anyone can do.

Comment: Update: I added clear:both to my .roundimage div and that seems to have fixed it. I think perhaps something to do with slow loading fonts screwing up sizing? Not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Because of your container is fixed width, you can add

```
margin: 20px 20px 20px 200px;
```

to your hero image's css.

Another good approach is to separate the rounded container from the image, becase the misaligment can be caused of delayed image loading. Container could be:

**html:**

```
<div id="heroimage">
    <img src="your_image_url">
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#heroimage {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hmm - thanks for your response. I updated the code (tomcritchlow.com) and it is still happening. Ideas?